# Frequency shift and phase shift (Doppler)

Tags: fft

I'm trying to apply a frequency shift to a generated despreading code in order to find and track a broadcast signal CDMA. Expected doppler shift range of the signal from center frequency would be approx +/- 5KHz. Based on freq2 = c/(c-orbitspeed) * freq1.

I am wanting to shift the code based on equations, assuming data set is made of complex numbers.

N = sample size
imaginary j = (0, 1)           same as notation i
new sample bin k = fft(generated code)[k] * e(-1 * j * 2 * PI * shift amount / N * k)

this "* j" makes the power an imaginary number part
e() being the same as *10^power, 10 being a real number (10, 0j)
do I need to follow the complex^complex rule to evaluate the e() expression? Then use the complex * complex to finish the product??

```
void adjust_CodeDoppler(int shift) // of fft data, apply fft in place first on gen_code
    {
        complex power;
        complex e;
        complex multiplier;
        power.m_re = 0;
        e.m_re = 10;
        e.m_im = 0;
        for(int n=0; n<N; n++)
        {
            power.m_im  = (-2*PI*shift/n*N); //*j part makes this the imag part of power
            double ph = phaseAngleComp(e); //for (10, 0j) is always 0 = 0/10
            double mg = magnatudeComp(e);  //for (10, 0j) is alwyas 10, sqrt( 10^2 + 0^2 )
            multiplier.m_re = pow(mg, power.m_re) * exp(-1 * power.m_im * ph) * cos(power.m_re * ph + power.m_im * log(mg) ); //= 10^power real part
            multiplier.m_im = pow(mg, power.m_re) * exp(-1 * power.m_im * ph) * sin(power.m_re * ph + power.m_im * log(mg) ); //= 10^power imag part
            shift_gen_code[n] = multiplier * gen_code[n]; //using complex operator *
        }
    }
```

Seperately to affect phase shift in data, Is this done in time domain?? Can this be suffiecient to adjust phase offsets without changing a NCO/VCO on the quad mixer?
Based on equations: also assuming data is alread I / Q  A/D converted
    ph = phase angle
n = bin position, time domain?
Wc = expected center frequency
Dpd = desired phase offset at time []
adjusted_ph = ph[n-1] + Wc + Dpd[n]
//limit phase shift
if(adjusted_ph[n] > 2* PI){adjusted_ph[n] = adjusted_ph[n] - 2*PI;}

Comment: I don't have training in electrical engineering so a lot of stuff (such as NCO/VCO/CDMA) is unfamiliar to me, but I'm having a really hard time understanding what you wrote, or even what you're trying to do, other than that you're trying to counteract a Doppler shift. I think users would be more inclined to answer if you wrote in coherent sentences, used punctuation, explained abbreviations, and used LaTeX.

Comment: I tried to edit it however it would not take the changes. Basically I receive in a signal in a small range. This is digitized into sign and magnatude I and Q bits representing the signal. Because there are many sources transmitting on the same center frequency, each source has a different spreading code or psudo noise code. In order to receive the actual data I must match a copy of the noise code in frequency and phase. Then by multiplication in frequency domain, the noise code is removed and only the data bits are left. I am wanting to do in the data what is often done in analog controls.

Comment: The first part of the question is mainly about the correct way to do the complex number math in c++. So I'm trying to represent a number ie: 5e-21 as 5 * 10^-21. However the complex numbers have real parts (representing I data) and imaginary parts (Q data). I do know this is done in frequency domain. The second part is asking about making phase adjustments to the sample data. Do these types of adjustments happen in time or frequency domain? Can this totally replace adjusting the oscilator on the mixer before the A/D converter?

Comment: I read through your code and tried to understand it, and (please don't take offense at this) I have to admit it's the most bizarre piece of code I've seen. Large parts of it, such as `pow(mg, power.m_re)`, `exp(-1 * power.m_im * ph)`, `power.m_re * ph `, etc. do absolutely nothing at all because they all automatically evaluate to either 0 or 1, and I'm completely baffled by your definitions such as $e=10$, or `power.m_im  = (-2*PI*shift/n*N)`.

Comment: Also, `multiplier.m_re` evaluates to $\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  \text{N} \text{shift} \log (10)}{n}\right)$ and `multiplier.m_im` evaluates to $\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  \text{N} \text{shift} \log (10)}{n}\right)$, neither of which make any sense, with the most obvious problem being that the $N$ and the $n$ are in the wrong places, so this is a hyperbolically-changing phase shift (if there's even such a thing), not a constant-frequency phase shift.

Comment: So as I said earlier I have no EE training, so correct me if I'm wrong, but is the basic idea that because of the Doppler shift, the I/Q data is rotating in the I/Q plane at 5 kHz, and you're trying to eliminate this rotation? What form does the I/Q data take, is it in the form of a stream of pair of real numbers of the form $\{I_k,Q_k\}$ for integer index $k$? What rate is the input stream of I/Q pairs coming in?

Comment: Assuming it comes in as pair of real numbers at a frequency of $f$ and that the Doppler frequency is $d$, then your Doppler corrected $\{I_k,Q_k\}$ pairs should be $\{I_k \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  d k}{f}\right)\pm Q_k \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  d
   k}{f}\right),Q_k \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  d
   k}{f}\right) \mp I_k \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  d k}{f}\right)\}$, where the plus or minus depends on whether it's plus or minus 5 kHz for the Doppler.

Comment: Again, I might just be ignorant, but I feel like this still might still be difficult to implement reliably due to Doppler frequency drift, assuming that the satellite is moving around. What if the satellite moves around, and its Doppler frequency changes to $4.999kHz$? Are there circuits specifically designed to counteract Doppler shifts, so that you don't have to struggle with reinventing the wheel? These are all questions which you're better qualified to answer than me, so maybe ask a professor or someone who works in industry about correcting Doppler shifts?

Comment: My friend was asking what the application for this was, as he was curious what kind of accuracy you're looking for that would make there a need for Doppler corrections. He was mentioning that the normal frequency drift for high-frequency oscillators should be well over 5 kHz, just due to thermal fluctuations in crystals and $1/f$ noise, etc, so he was thinking that Doppler drift should be only a small factor in contributing to frequency drift.

Comment: I am building a gps reciever. There are methods in analog to adjust for doppler by changing the input to a Numerically Controlled Oscillator (NCO) or a Voltage Controled Oscilator (VCO). This changes the frequency of the mixer that is removing the carrier and producing the I /Q split. However when doing so each time the circuit needs to check the tracking on a satiellite it must adjust the oscillator making that data stream only viable for the satellite it is looking for at that time. What I want to do is examine the signal data in freq domain and compare to a local despreading code.

Comment: The despreading code will run in a delay lock loop so it will adjust for code shift. IF I get the doppler data adjustment working then it will track the doppler shift for each satellite as well, adjusting for shift each time it checks the tracking. My thought is to do this in freq domain to avoid running FFT on the input data more than once per sample period. Then I can check for all the sats I am tracking and then run an aquire loop which is more demanding FFT wise to check for new or lost satellites.

Comment: My plan is for the I Q data to be incomming in 16 bit buffered samples from the A/D converter. These will be normalized to 1 / -1 values in the buffer. The generated code will be a psuedo random noise code chipped out to match each satellite's despreading code. Right now my plan is to have 4096 samples/chips per millis. I may need to increase the samples/ millis but I'm hoping to limit the RAM requirements for the buffers needed to compute this.

Comment: The equation I was working with, may not be correct but as I read it: shifted sample in frequency domain: f'[k] = f[k]* 10^(-1*2*Pi*j* shift / k * sample size). I am assuming the equation is correct for the purpose. I admit its been 15+ years since the last math class I had in college. So I thought that since j is imaginary I would have to make e a complex number. So I defined the e.m_re = 10 (real part of e) and e.m_im = 0 (imag part of e). The train of thought was to multiply an exponent that was imaginary * e, I needed e to be a complex number.

Comment: So hopefully following the rules for complex number ^ complex number I "should" get the right result for multiplier.m_re (real part) and multiplier.m_im (imaginary part). Then doing a complex number * complex number to get the shifted frequency domain I and Q. Again already FFT converted to freq domain. I honestly do not know if I am on target here on the math or not.

Comment: Someone else suggested doing in time domain t'[k] = t[k] * exp(j*2*Pi* shift * k/sample size).